# Postfix IP address client restriction

Tags: ip-address, postfix-mta, restriction, outbound

One of the email accounts on my mail server was compromised. Spammers figured out one of the email account user-id and password. Since they were authenticated, postfix allowed all of the spam to be sent. One option is to set `smtpd_client_message_rate_limit`, but that doesn't help if we want to send a larger than normal number of emails.

**I would like to put in a rule that only accept outbound email from IP addresses of email clients (Thunderbird, Outlook, Notes, etc...) from our office.** I know the IP's of all of the client machines.

I have looked but can't find a rule that doesn't restrict inbound also. I must be missing something. Any help is appreciated. I can't believe this isn't possible.

Cheers
-Jeff

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove the

```
permit_sasl_authenticated
```

line from your postfix's `main.cf` files and instead just leave

```
permit_mynetworks,
```

and add the IP addresses of your office in the "mynetworks" list.

Comment: Jon, so smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_sender_login_mismatch ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. When I made the change, I was able to send from an IP that is not in $mynetworks list.